# Is it possible to add names to EKS nodes AFTER creating the nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

I had created eks cluster and node group using Terraform. I forgot to add names to the nodes.

Now the nodes have been successfully created but without names.

Is it possible to add names (say using eksctl) to nodes now that they are already in running state?

Is it possible to do so without recreating/destroying the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

`EKSCTL` can't manage cluster not created by `EKSCTL` (yet). However the EC2 instance name is basically a tag. I don't know TF but I assume that if you re apply your Terraform code with a name schema to be assigned to the nodes it would only apply the tag to the instances? It should not redeploy the instances to add a name. You could try this on a test cluster.